# Comparing cameras from older smartphones to cameras from recently released devices

Tags: cameraphones, smartphone

Usually when new smartphones appear in close succession their cameras are well compared on tech sites or magazines, for example [like here](http://www.businessinsider.com/oneplus-3-vs-galaxy-s7-camera-comparison-2016-6?IR=T/#the-oneplus-doesnt-quite-have-the-galaxy-s7s-depth-of-field-but-its-close-5) the S7 and the OnePlus3.

But are there such tests which compare newer models with older ones. Surely, most are interested to choose from what currently is on the market, but sometimes people (like me now) want to know whats gained if they buy a new device. So are there comparison tests like the above that span "smartphone generations", for example comparing a Nexus 4 vs the new Samsung S7 or something like that? Surely most of the time the new devices score higher, but it would be still interesting how much better the results are, and if its worth.

Comment: We certainly can't answer "if its worth [upgrading]?" as that's a personal judgment only you can make.

Comment: Sure, and exactly to make this judgement I need such comparisons :) Maybe to make it more precise, I am **not** asking if its worth upgrading, but I am looking for comparisons (like the cited one) between older phones vs newer ones to make my personal judgement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try GSMArena. They have detailed reviews for a variety of models of phones, going back several years. This is includes sample photos from the camera.

They have photos from each phone of a standard scene. So you can use the [Photo Compare Tool](http://www.gsmarena.com/piccmp.php3) to directly compare different models. eg comparison of the [Nexus 4 vs Samsung S7](http://www.gsmarena.com/piccmp.php3?idType=1&idPhone1=5048&idPhone2=7821).

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking because tech moves at such a high rate you dont tend to get reviews of the latest models in comparison with a model from more than a year ago (because technically they classed as obsolete - even if they are still very capable). Most sites compare the previous version e.g how the S7 performs over the S6.

The good thing about the internet is that its pretty easy to find the older phone reviews and specs and do a little self comparison with the newer phone you are interested in....funnily enoough I have a nexus 4 and am looking at the S7

If you upgrade from a 2yr old + phone in a similar price range you should notice alot of difference in performance on the camera in terms of speed, noise, low light performance etc etc. If you upgrade from a year old phone you may find the upgrade is evolutionary as opposed to revolutionary, which is why I usually wait a few years before upgrading.